# Update the rank column based on the total of a group

Tags: sqlite, ranking

I wrote the following code in **SQLite**:

```
CREATE TABLE payments (
  customerNumber REAL NOT NULL,
  checkNumber TEXT NOT NULL,
  paymentDate TEXT NOT NULL,
  amount REAL NOT NULL,
  rank REAL default 0,
  PRIMARY KEY  (customerNumber,checkNumber)
);

insert  into payments(customerNumber,checkNumber,paymentDate,amount) values(103,'HQ336336','2004-10-19 00:00:00',6066.78);
insert  into payments(customerNumber,checkNumber,paymentDate,amount) values(103,'JM555205','2003-06-05 00:00:00',14571.44);
insert  into payments(customerNumber,checkNumber,paymentDate,amount) values(112,'BO864823','2004-12-17 00:00:00',14191.12);
insert  into payments(customerNumber,checkNumber,paymentDate,amount) values(112,'HQ55022','2003-06-06 00:00:00',32641.98);
insert  into payments(customerNumber,checkNumber,paymentDate,amount) values(121,'MA302151','2004-11-28 00:00:00',34638.14);
insert  into payments(customerNumber,checkNumber,paymentDate,amount) values(121,'KI831359','2004-11-04 00:00:00',17876.32);
insert  into payments(customerNumber,checkNumber,paymentDate,amount) values(161,'KG644125','2005-02-02 00:00:00',12692.19);
insert  into payments(customerNumber,checkNumber,paymentDate,amount) values(161,'NI908214','2003-08-05 00:00:00',38675.13);
insert  into payments(customerNumber,checkNumber,paymentDate,amount) values(181,'CM564612','2004-04-25 00:00:00',22602.36);
insert  into payments(customerNumber,checkNumber,paymentDate,amount) values(181,'GQ132144','2003-01-30 00:00:00',5494.78);
```

Now my question is, **How can I update the rank column in the table based on the ranking of "total(amount) from payments group by customerNumber"?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit** (removed SQL Server code, SQLite doesn't support joins in update statements):

I think this should be ok:

```sql
drop table if exists ranks;

create temp table ranks (
    rank integer primary key,
    customerNumber real,
    total real
);

insert into ranks
select null, customerNumber, total(amount) as total
from payments
group by customerNumber
order by total desc;


update payments set
    rank = (
        select rank from ranks 
        where customerNumber = payments.customerNumber
    );

select * from payments;
```

**Added:**

Here is very very dirty way to do it in one statement, it uses very specific subqueries to rank (it's some kind of SQLite row number) each customer. As I've said, many many sybqueries but that's the price to get it work in one query without using join in update.

```sql
update payments set
    rank = (
        select
            (select count(0) from (select total(amount) as t, customerNumber as c
                    from payments group by customerNumber order by t desc) t1
            where t1.t >= t2.t) as rank
        from (select total(amount) as t, customerNumber as c from payments group by customerNumber order by t desc) 
        t2 where t2.c = payments.customerNumber order by t2.t desc
    );
```

Comment: It is just updating the table as rank=total. But What I want is, to give "rating" to the customerNumber based on the total. i.e the customerNumber with highest 'total' will have rank '1'. the second heighest will have rank '2'.

Comment: Also, the query is executing only after removal of '#' from the code.

Comment: I've change it, but I'm not sure whether an update with temp table in the middle is good for you - it's not one statement update. `#` - is SQL Server habit, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response :). This statement works but doesn't meet my requirements. If you can, please help me with writing the code in one update statement or atleast let me know whether it is feasible to write it in one update statement. I'm new (a noob) to SQL/SQLite.

Comment: Thats awesome. Thanks a ton for the help. :)